# Preposition for dialog box, form, display, interface

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

I wrote this sentence

> The software consists of a graphical user interface (**by /in /on/ through/ using**) which the user (**performs/ takes/ does**) some spelling tests on a given list of words.

The bold words are those that I don't know the suitable one.

What is the correct preposition for things done through a software user interface (Ironically, I myself use through in this sentence of question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the slightly formal language you're using in the rest of the sentence:

> The software consists of a graphical user interface **through** which
>   the user **takes** some spelling tests on a given list of words.

**Through** as in the software is the means of performing the action.

The second part of the sentence, *"Take a test"* is the usual form, but you may want to consider, *"through which the user is tested on their spelling with a given list of words."* as an alternative that fits more with the general tone.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to say:

The software consists of a graphical user interface, **on** which the user can take spelling tests.

Otherwise, you can be more wordy:

The software consists of a graphical user interface, on which the student is given a list of words to test his/her spelling.

Comment: by test I mean quiz, he should do some spelling quiz

Comment: ok, I've changed my answer